# What type of instrument can I use to determine my current distance from the center point of Earth?

Tags: gravity, earth, distance

Immediately, I think of a scale, but is there better way? I can only imagine weighing an object of known mass with an extremely precise scale.

I am asking because I would like to be able to address absolute elevations relative to the center of Earth as ternary component of the geographic coordinate system.

Comment: How much accuracy do you need? And why?

Comment: Try a GPS module.

Comment: Essentially you want the height above sea level, right?

Comment: A scale certainly won't work. The variation due to local geography is larger than that dues to distance. Geologists use precision mapping of the local gravitational strength to help locate ores, oil and water.

Comment: @lucas Ideally a few meters.

Comment: @lemon No, not altitude (relative to sea level), but absolute distance (Earth radius + elevation at that specific location).

Comment: Do you need this for military purposes?!! This is a very very high accuracy. The radius of the earth is about $6500\; \textrm{km}$.

Comment: @lucas Haha; no (the average is 6371 km). I edited the question to clarify. It's simply for the utility of being able to describe a specific location within or near Earth in a single system rather than multiple ones put together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like GPS is best here.  The position of the antenna is determined first in coordinates relative to the center of the earth, and then translated onto the ellipsoid and geoid.  So finding the position relative to the center of the earth should actually be more accurate than finding its altitude relative to sea level.   (Survey-grade can be centimeter resolution).

However, a consumer receiver isn't going to give you any of the information from that intermediate step.  I think you'll need to find some sort of survey-grade unit that can provide such data.

If there were a local measurement that would give distance to the center of the earth, it would make an easy way to determine the size of the planet.  There is no simple local measurement that can do so.

Comment: So what you're saying is that satellite triangulation can provide it to me because all of their rotational axes are the same Earth center?

Comment: Analysis of the satellite orbit directly determines earth's center of mass.  The non-spherical earth and the moon perturb the orbits to some extent, but these differences can be corrected.   Then the sats are tracked in a reference frame with the center of the earth at the origin, so distance to this point is easy to calculate.

Comment: Cool—I didn't realize that distance to earth's center is the basis of GPS location. 

Comment: Do GPS calculations take into account the equatorial bulge due to Earth's rotation? If it is above sea level, you would have to look up sea level radius for a given latitude.

Comment: Yes.  The first lookup is to the reference ellipsoid (which has the equatorial bulge), then to the reference geoid (which gives sea-level differences from the ellipsoid).  Example: https://microem.ru/files/2012/08/GPS.G1-X-00006.pdf